# Fetching number of rows after PDO execute

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I am trying to show the number of rows found in the database after the searching.

Here is my code:

```
$city =  $_POST['city'];
 $bloodType = $_POST['donorType'];

     $q = $db->prepare("SELECT count(*) FROM  `users` AS numusers WHERE `city` = :city  AND `bloodType` = :bloodType");
     $q->bindValue(":city",$city,PDO::PARAM_INT);
     $q->bindValue(":bloodType",$bloodType);
     $q->execute();

    while($row = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    echo "<p align='center'><h5> There is/are <span class='red-text'>".$row['numusers']."</span> available donor(s) found.
    You must be a <b><a href='register.php'>registered user</a></b> to view their details.</h5></p>";
      }
```

That's the last try I did. And I get this error message
`Notice: Undefined index: numusers

How do I solve that Tips ?

Comment: It should be like this SELECT count(*) as numusers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create alias of `count(*)`

```
SELECT count(*) AS numusers..
```

It would be

```
$q = $db->prepare("SELECT count(*) AS  numusers FROM `users` WHERE `city` = :city  AND `bloodType` = :bloodType");
```

Comment: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS `numusers` `users` WHERE `city` = '3' AND `bloodType` = '4''` I receive this error message

Comment: remove backtick from `numusers` just  use `SELECT count(*) AS numusers..`

Comment: In Updated question you create alias of table you need to create alias of `count(*)` check updated answer!!

Comment: Thank you! I place `AS numusers` after the `FROM `users`` I didn't don't it would be that sensitive lol. Thanks and God bless :)

Comment: Will tick check after 5 minutes :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a special method in PDO to retrieve this kind of data - a single value returned by the query, [PDOStatement::fetchColumn()](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#fetchcolumn). So you don't have to hassle with aliases at all.

Besides, a while loop is superfluous here.

```
$city =  $_POST['city'];
$bloodType = $_POST['donorType'];

$q = $db->prepare("SELECT count(*) FROM  `users` WHERE `city` = :city  AND `bloodType` = :bloodType");
$q->bindValue(":city", $city, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$q->bindValue(":bloodType", $bloodType);
$q->execute();
$numusers = $q->fetchColumn();

echo "<p align='center'><h5> There is/are <span class='red-text'>$numusers</span> available donor(s) found.
You must be a <b><a href='register.php'>registered user</a></b> to view their details.</h5></p>";
```